# Javascript : Programmatically add words to URL

Tags: javascript, search, greasemonkey

**My problem**:

I'm tired of manually adding "dog" every time I use Google.I do not want the "dog" appearing in my search results.

For example:It should be like this

https://www.google.com/search?q=cat`+-dog`

https://www.google.com/search?q=baseball`+-dog`

**CODE**:Credit goes to krowe.

`dog` replaced with `-torrent-watch-download`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Tamper with Google Results
// @namespace  http://superuser.com/users/145045/krowe
// @version    0.1
// @description  This just modifies google results to exclude certain things.
// @match      http://*.google.com
// @match      https://*.google.com
// @copyright  2014+, KRowe
// ==/UserScript==


function GM_main () {
    window.onload = function () {
      var targ = window.location;
      if(targ && targ.href && targ.href.match('https?:\/\/www.google.com/.+#q=.+') && targ.href.search("/+-torrent/+-watch/+-download")==-1) {
        targ.href = targ.href +"+-torrent+-watch+-download";
      }
    };
}

//-- This is a standard-ish utility function:
function addJS_Node(text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D=document, scriptNode = D.createElement('script');
    if(runOnLoad) scriptNode.addEventListener("load", runOnLoad, false);
    scriptNode.type = "text/javascript";
    if(text) scriptNode.textContent = text;
    if(s_URL) scriptNode.src = s_URL;
    if(funcToRun) scriptNode.textContent = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';
    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild(scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node (null, null, GM_main);
```

The problem is that you MUST type the search string in the address bar for this to work. The problem with typing into Google search directly is that the onload event doesn't fire.
I want this script to work in Google search

Any room for improvement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Google is working on hash, you could try:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(ev)
{
  if(! /[#&]q=(?:[^&]*\+)?-dog(?:\+|$)/i.test(location.hash))
    location.hash += '+-dog';
});
```

You can dynamically prepare a RegExp by string with `new RegExp('the expression', modifiers)`.

Consider to implement an alternative for the query version of google which is used as fallback on heavy load (slow script execution).

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say, that I'm a noob at programming,Can you please check to see if  the script works with Google search.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, I had testet this with Scriptish (GreaseMonkey fork) on Google. It's just hard coded with your example "-dog". You should adapt the code to your needs with dynamic build of the expression.